# SSH into network using Putty

Tags: putty

I use Putty to connect to a host (via its IP) and enter my username and password.

The host always returns an `Access Denied`, though my password is correct.
Is this an issue I can fix within putty or is this something else ?

Comment: Is the destination host Windows, Linux another OS?
Do you have access to the destination host? Can you log on to the destination host normally and check that the SSH server is running, listening on the correct port (usually 22) and that your login has access to use SSH. It's possible that you have not been granted access via SSH if you don't manage the host.

Comment: @Enigman I'm on a windows system and I'm logged on to the correct server and it accepts my username.

Comment: Can you SSH/log in to the server from a different machine besides the Windows machine that fails?  Also, how do you know the password is entered correctly?  Maybe different keyboard mappings?

Comment: I'd recommend enabling session logging on Putty and seeing what it actually reports as the log may report back what the server is replying back (credential issue/user rights etc.) As an example, in the Attachmate Reflection SSH server a user or group can be given access to connect via SSH and unless you or your group have been given specific access it will give an access denied. In earlier versions you also needed to have the "Log on Locally" right to be able to SSH. You might need to check the SSH server log at the other end to get more detail.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot ssh to a Windows machine, so I assume there is another problem. Have you tried using nmap? It comes with Linux by standard, but for Windows you'll need to download it:
   http://download.cnet.com/Online-Nmap-Port-Scan/3000-18510_4-75532036.html

The nmap results should show you the available ports open, I would start from there. Also, try to take in consideration a firewall rule - it can also block ssh access, the nmap would show that.

Answer (score 0):

The "Access Denied" is usually due to wrong combination of username/password. Assuming you are connecting from Windows machine using Putty to a *nix server of some sort. (Please correct me if this assumption is wrong)

A few things that you can check (Sorry if I'm pointing out obvious things):

1. Are you sure you got the correct username?
2. Are you sure you got the correct password (with the correct capitalisation)?
3. Is your account a valid, non-expired, not locked account on the remote server? (Confirm this with the server admin or other user who has access)
4. Has your sys-admin changed something on the server end to prevent you from logging in (resetting your password without telling you, or set the server to only allow login using key rather than password - again check with your sysadmin)

Those are a few things I can think of for now.. I'll add more when I can think of more things to try.

Hope this helps.